# Spring boot reuse controller method with @PreAuthorize in code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have controller annotated with @PreAuthorize and i want to reuse its methods inside code(so we prepare code for creation of microservices)

But Im getting this error An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext when I try to reuse any method.

Is anything like this possible?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users'))
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminUsersApi {

    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<UserResponseDto> getUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers().stream().map(userMapper::toUserResponse).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

} 

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WalletService {
    private final AdminUsersApi adminUsersApi;

    private void customFunction() {
       adminUsersApi.getUsers();
    }
}
```

Or lets say i have 2 microservices : Wallet, Users

And I want to make request from Wallet to Users, without taking current users authorities(i would like to define some kind of api key, which would have certain roles)

What is best approach?

Comment: Please provides some code examples

Comment: i provided example